# What to do after this to compare interaction.customId

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a Multiplayer RPS in discord using Buttons but i cant seem to find a way to compare `inteaction.customId` of both collectors to get the result. The challenger and the Member who is challenged have to respond in their DMs.

Please tell me a way to get `inteaction.customId` from these two colletectors or a way through which i can determine Results.

This is the collector for challenger

```js
acollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                            if (interaction.customId === 'rock') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Rock**!')
                            } else if (interaction.customId === 'paper') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Paper**!')
                            } else if (interaction.customId === 'scissor') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Scissors**!')
                            }

                        })
```

This is the collector for The member who is being challenged:

````js
ocollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
                            if (interaction.customId === 'rock') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Rock**!')
                            } else if (interaction.customId === 'paper') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Paper**!')
                            } else if (interaction.customId === 'scissor') {
                                RPSbuttons.components.forEach(e => e.setDisabled(true))
                                interaction.update({emebes: [RPSembed], components: [RPSbuttons]})
                                interaction.user.send('You Choose **Scissors**!')
                            }

                        })```
````

Comment: I don't think you should have two different collectors here. Why don't you use a single one?

Comment: They are in from different user's DM